# WebStorm auto import not working when pasting

Tags: reactjs, ide, webstorm, auto-import

I've got a React component as follows:

```
<CodeMirrorReact onChange={onChangeTest} code={multiLineCode}></CodeMirrorReact>
```

When I start typing ... `<CodeMi` ... a drop down appears. I can select the component from the dropdown and WebStorm auto completes for me AND (more importantly) does an auto import for the component by adding the following import statement:

```
import CodeMirrorReact from '../CodeMirrorReact/index'
```

Great!

However, when I copy and paste the above component code, WebStorm does not do the auto import. <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> does not work either.

Anyone know how to fix it so auto imports work when pasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto import on paste is not a feature of the stable version of WebStorm.

However it has been [added to the WebStorm EAP for the next version (2017.3)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/webstorm-2017-3-eap/#import-on-paste).